# trying to find record that includes # in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a access vba application. when i try to search for invoice using the

```
DoCmd.FindRecord strOrdNum, acEntire, False, acDown, False, acCurrent, True
```

It works when the strOrdNum is something like 123 or 1111. However for the records with strOrdNum that has "#" in them it does not work. For example for one of the records I have 11234#223, but it does not find it. Any ideas on how I can deal with these cases. Thanks

Comment: You may need to look into the [wildcard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HP005188185.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @OverMind mentioned, I think it's a wildcard issue.  This worked for me.  Replace:

```
DoCmd.FindRecord strOrdNum, acEntire, False, acDown, False, acCurrent, True
```

with:

```
DoCmd.FindRecord Replace(strOrdNum, "#", "[#]"), acEntire, False, acDown, False, acCurrent, True
```

This will force it to search for the literal.